# How can I see the data frame output

Tags: pandas, jupyter-lab

I am trying to output the df for the dataset. However, I can see the title of the table but not the actual data. It seems that it all aligned the right and hid. Is there any way to get it to show[image]

Comment: Use `pd.read_csv(filename, sep=';')`.

Comment: Thanks, @SandeepKadapa now I have (...) in the middle of the table. how can I see the data which are bidding inside these?

Comment: you cannot see entire data of your csv file at once, this is limitation of pandas. But if you want to see, you need to change display setting from formatting of pandas which is quite not easy.

Comment: Thanks a lot .. I can accept this as answer

Comment: @Nano if you want to display more number of rows. you can change the settings of pandas display like this:

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 100)

Comment: I didn't mean the rows. I mean I want to see the entire row, like all the columns in that row cuz in the middle of the row there are (...)

Comment: pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None) solved my problem. Thanks all!